# My link_to routes changing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm currently using devise with the following link_to url to "submit" a Resource (resources_controller, resource.rb model)

This is in the menu:

```
<li><%= link_to "Submit Resource", :action => 'new', :controller => 'resources' %></li>
```

It works fine if I'm not on a devise login page (user signup, user login, etc)

otherwise it changes the url from /resources/new

to this:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets?action=new&controller=devise%2Fresources
```

The only reason i linked it using the first piece of code above is because I'm not sure if theres a better way to link to a particular REST action directly for a given controller (I'm not using :index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<%= link_to "Submit Resource", new_resource_path %>`. Before use it you should make sure if you have line `resources :resources` line in your `routes.rb`